# _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-Label"

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I'm creating a mp3 player(learning from tutorial), and I ran into this error which I didn't understand. I used the pygame and tkinter module, and python said the error came in line 49, in  my_menu.add_cascade(Label="Add Songs", Menu=add_song_menu)

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3289, in add_cascade
    self.add('cascade', cnf or kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3284, in add
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'add', itemType) +
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-Label"
```

This was my code(so far):

```
from tkinter import *
import pygame

pygame.init()

root = Tk()
root.title("MP3 Player")
root.geometry("500x300")


# Add Song Function
def add_song():
    pass


# Create Playlist Box
song_box = Listbox(root, bg="black", fg="green", width=60).pack(pady=20)

# Create Player Control Frames
controls_frame = Frame(root)
controls_frame.pack()

# Define Player Control Buttons
back_btn_img = PhotoImage(file="back.png")
forward_btn_img = PhotoImage(file="download (1).png")
play_btn_img = PhotoImage(file="download.png")
pause_btn_img = PhotoImage(file="12-512.png")
stop_btn_img = PhotoImage(file="stop.png")

# Create Player Control Buttons
back_btn = Button(controls_frame, image=back_btn_img, borderwidth=0)
forward_btn = Button(controls_frame, image=forward_btn_img, borderwidth=0)
play_btn = Button(controls_frame, image=play_btn_img, borderwidth=0)
pause_btn = Button(controls_frame, image=pause_btn_img, borderwidth=0)
stop_btn = Button(controls_frame, image=stop_btn_img, borderwidth=0)

back_btn.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10)
forward_btn.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)
play_btn.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10)
pause_btn.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10)
stop_btn.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10)

# Create Menu
my_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=my_menu)

# Add Add Song Menu
add_song_menu = Menu(my_menu)
my_menu.add_cascade(Label="Add Songs", Menu=add_song_menu)
add_song_menu.add_command(Label="Add One Song To Playlist", command=add_song)

root.mainloop()
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: its `my_menu.add_cascade(label="Add Songs", Menu=add_song_menu)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the "Label" should be lowercase (http://zetcode.com/tkinter/menustoolbars/):

```
my_menu.add_cascade(label="Add Songs", Menu=add_song_menu)
add_song_menu.add_command(label="Add One Song To Playlist", command=add_song)
```

Answer (score 0):

`my_menu.add_cascade(lable='Options',command='')`

You should use a small 'l' in lable.

Answer (score -1):

```
my_menu.add_cascade(label = "Add songs", menu = add_song_menu)
add_song_menu.add_command(label = "Add one Song to Playlist",command=add_song)
```

Try this

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @user15070659 this is not an edit. It is a code only answer.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.